# On an internal link, e.g. to #id is there an event fired that I can attach a handler to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a webpage which has various "internal" links on it to various objects with various ids.
The webpage also has an attachment to the scroll event to hide / display certain items when scrolled by a certain amount.

I'd like to trigger the scroll event handler when the page navigates to another section after clicking on one of these links.

The click event is fired before navigation so I can't attach to that, as it needs to make decisions based on the new location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event? It's [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange) these days. (Modernizr has a test and lot's of polyfills, just in case...)

BTW, if you want to save the locations check out the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). history.pushState should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "onChange" event being fired when you click on a hash link on a single page. The only way contemporary (AJAXed) pages monitor hash change is using an interval after which a JavaScript function is called to do  that check.

So in other words, the only possibility is to save last hash location (`document.location.hash`) on timely basis and navigate back to the old location if some condition is not met.